# Emacs: Build a menu from items in a list

Tags: emacs

Back with another Emacs question. I'm trying to make my package add a menu, but I'm running into some problems here.

I have a list with strings, and I for each item in this list I want to add an entry to the menu, calling a function with the string as an argument. Now the problem is that I cannot hardcode this menu, since the list is supposed to be edited by the user.

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
(dolist (item my-list)
  (define-key global-map [menu-bar my-menu item]
              (cons item `(lambda () (interactive) (my-function ,item)))))
```

Now the problem is that I only get one menu item, at `<menu-bar> <my-menu> <item>`. How can I use the value of the variable "item" in `[menu-bar my-menu item]`, instead of the literal string "item"?

Also, having the lambda in the cons like that works, but I'm not quite happy with it - is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your first question:

```lisp
(dolist (item my-list)
  (define-key global-map (vector 'menu-bar 'my-menu item)
              (cons item `(lambda () (interactive) (my-function ,item)))))
```

Comment: Or you can use `\`[menu-bar my-menu ,item]`.

Comment: Yes that is an alternative that is often used in internal libraries.